# ngx-mat-datetime-picker in angular/REST-application does not update the value with custom DateAdapter

Tags: angular, angular-material, datetimepicker, date-fns

I'm trying to use the [ngx-mat-datetime-picker](https://h2qutc.github.io/angular-material-components/datetimepicker) in an angular.io application with a custom date adapter, based on this [gist](https://gist.github.com/JoniJnm/412325c073805437c68430b11407e11b.). My application talks to a REST-API, that has elements with a datetime field in the format `2020-01-08T01:02:03.000Z`.

```
{ "idxdevice": 123, "devname": "test", "devoutdated": "2020-05-01T09:42:27.281Z" }
```

After retrieving the element I convert it to a JavaScript-Date-Element in the `detail-component`'s get()-Method:

```
get(): void {
  const idxdevice = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('idx');
  this.deviceService.getDevice(idxdevice).subscribe(device => {        
    this.device = device;
    this.device.devoutdated = new Date(device.devoutdated)
  });
}
```

My input field on the frontend looks like this:

```
<mat-form-field class="detail-form-field">
  <mat-label>Outdated since</mat-label>
  <input matInput [ngxMatDatetimePicker]="datetimepicker" [value]="device.devoutdated" (input)="device.devoutdated = $event.target.value" />
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="datetimepicker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <ngx-mat-datetime-picker #datetimepicker></ngx-mat-datetime-picker>
</mat-form-field>
```

The DATE_FORMAT for the date-adapter looks like this

```
export const MAT_DATE_FNS_DATE_FORMATS = {
  parse: {
    dateInput: 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss',
  },
  display: {
    dateInput: 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss',
    monthYearLabel: 'LLL y',
    dateA11yLabel: 'MMMM d, y',
    monthYearA11yLabel: 'MMMM y',
  }
};
```

If I open up the browser, the result in the input field is as expected. Now if I change the datetime in the input field via the datepicker (in fact, changing values via keyboard empties the input field and will not let me insert anything but sometimes a single number), the PUT-request back to the server contains the "previous" datetime and not the one I've selected in the input field.

From my point of view the `devoutdated`-field is not updated on changing the date (but it works for other fields like `devname`). My first guess is that it has something to do with the Date-field that should be converted back to a string when talking to the API. But on the other side I think that this is another issue and not related to the update of the field, that should be covered by the date-adapter.

Any suggestions what's causing this issue?